# How to display a "print" error when the user enters wrong character or invalid input data?

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to know if there is an easy way to display a error for a wrong character or invalid input data.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Step 1: Create new Scanner object.
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);         

    // Step 2: Prompt the user to enter today's day.
    System.out.print("Enter today’s day as an Integer (0-6): ");
    int Today = input.nextInt();

    // Step 3: Prompt the user to enter the number of days elapsed since today.
    System.out.print("Enter the number of days elapsed since today as an Integer: ");
    int DaysElapsed= input.nextInt();

    // Step 4: Compute the future day.
    int FutureDay = (Today + DaysElapsed) % 7;

    // Step 5: Printing the results.
        // Step 5.1: Today's day result depending the case.
        System.out.print("Today is ");
            // Step 5.2: Future day result depending the case.
        System.out.print(" and the future day is ");
```

Comment: With an `if` statement, and either an `Exception`, a print statement, or a `System.err.println`

Comment: But what about Exception handling? The idea is implement something that makes the code more legible and simple.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are only expecting 'int' here from the `scanner.nextInt()` It will throw an `InputMismatchException` exception. So you can easily validate your input for `int` here like this -

```
try {
   int Today = input.nextInt();
   int DaysElapsed= input.nextInt();
} catch (InputMismatchException){
   System.err.println("Input is not an integer");
}
```

[Scanner.nextInt()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()) also throws `NoSuchElementException` and `IllegalStateException` exceptions
Moreover you can validate whetehr an input date is valid by using conditions (`today>=1 && today=<31`)

Comment: Thank you for your help @Razib. I tried with this also, I think merging this with the while statement it will works

Answer (score 0):

With nextInt() you already filter the allowed values to integers. But if you want the user to enter values in a limited range you could use something like this:

```
    int Today = 0;

    if (input.hasNextInt()) {
        if (input.nextInt() < 32 && input.nextInt() > 0) { //should be between 0-32

            Today = input.nextInt();

        } else {

            throw new Exception("Number must be between 0-32");
        }
    }
```

**Edit:**

If you want to continue on error:

```
    int Today = 0;
    if(input.hasNextInt()) {

        Today = input.nextInt();
        while (!(Today > 0 && Today < 32)){

            System.out.println("Number must be between 0-32");
            Today = input.nextInt();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes I did that, but the idea is to not let the user continue, and show the error, until he put a number for example between 0-32 as you chose. I tried with do, while also, and the error showing with println, but the program ended. The idea is the program continue until the user put the correct input

Comment: Edited my code.  But if you really want an exception to be thrown I'd prefer @Razib's answer.

Comment: I did but it says "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score." ahahah I started yesterday with this. And in the comments, I didn't know about the quotes, and now i'm not able to do comments!

Comment: Haha no problem mate. Thanks anyway.